# Print several lines inside one column in the terminal (with a c program)

Tags: c, terminal, formatting, multiple-columns, zsh

I would like to format the output of the program according to column. When the text of a column is wider than the column, I would like it to be printed on several lines which would however stay in that column

I get an output of the form:

```
col1    thats a very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long string that doesn't fit on one line in the terminal and its beginning should start indented
```

Instead I would like to have an output of the form:

```
col1    thats a very very very very very very very very very very very very very ve
        ry very very very very long string that doesn't fit on one line in the term
        inal and its beginning should start indented
```

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  char col1[] = "col1";
  char col2[] = "thats a very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long string that doesn't fit on one line in the terminal and its beginning should start indented";
  printf("%s\t%s\n", col1, col2);
  return 0;
}
```

Is is something that is C specific or is it specific to the terminal?

Comment: you would need to implement that yourself, the line wrap of most terminals doesn't work like that

Comment: It's probably based on max terminal line length (default 80). You can put '\n' where you need a new line, or implement own function, which will split string after desired length.

Comment: You won't get the indentation with most wrapping programs.  It gets even more fun if you have 3 columns, and it is the middle one that has the most data to fit into limited space.  You have to define the line width and the starting offset and width of each column, and process the data for each field accordingly.  You can also go for word wrapping (so that words aren't broken in the middle), but then you have to worry about very long words that are longer than the column's width.  Do you hyphenate? And it's quite easy with constant-width fonts; there's more complexity with variable-width fonts.

Comment: ISO C has no notion of a terminal, or any specific I/O device for that matter. It deals entirely in [streams](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/FILE), and it is up to the terminal emulator to interpret those streams and give them visual meaning. Any serious answer to this question will be OS/terminal emulator specific (to even begin you will need to know the "width" of the terminal - this is `ioctl` / `terminfo` territory). Consider using a TUI library like [`curses`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/curses/info)/[`ncurses`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ncurses/info).

Comment: ecjb, If `char col1[] = "thats a very very very.... start indented";`, just like `col2[]`, what output would be expected?